# What is priority -20 of evsmanager in android automotive?

Tags: android, android-automotive

In Camera HAL of android automotive, What is priority -20 in evs manager class

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're referring to .rc file for evs manager service (/packages/services/Car/evs/manager/android.automotive.evs.manager@1.0.rc).

The explanation for this and all other possible options can be found in the official [Android Init Language](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md) documentation:

> `priority <priority>`
>
> > Scheduling priority of the service process. This value has to be in range -20 to 19.  Default priority is 0. Priority is set via setpriority().

Therefore, `priority -20` means the service will be scheduled with the lowest possible priority.